# How to decrypt an old DVD encrypted with aespipe

Tags: iso, disk-encryption

I encrypted some DVDs a long time ago like this:

exec mkisofs -r $basename | aespipe -e aes256 > $fullname

Now I'm trying to decrypt them and I don't know how to do it anymore.

The encryption expected a set of tools that don't work or exist anymore.

How do I decrypt the files now? Any idea?

Thanks,

L

P.S. The full method i used is probably this:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=579173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory (note this creates an unencrypted copy of your data):

```
# place DVD in drive
cat /dev/cdrom | aespipe -d -e aes256 > your.iso
mount your.iso /mnt
```

Looks for files at /mnt.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and I couldn't get it to work. It may be because I don't have the correct password but I don't know for  sure.

When I try to mount the ISO it says that it can't locate the blocks. Since it takes a while to execute the operation, and I have a lot of file to check, I'll try the virtual box approach which should let me test many passwords without being forced to decrypt the 4 GB every time.

Comment: Note you can copy the cdrom to a file then do something like `dd if=cdrom.data bs=1M count=1 | aespipe ...` to just decrypt the first 1MB then you can look for a valid ISO header. Or you could probably use an even smaller block like 4KB or something. That should be way faster if you're trying to find the password.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Then I can use file or something to check what the header says...

And it works! Thanks! Alll I  need to do now is go thru the DVDs and figure out the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the password, a way to solve that is to install an older version of Ubuntu/Debian that has toolset you need. It could be installed onto a VM for example or an external disk/pendrive you can then boot from.

You can download the iso images for older Ubuntu versions [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) and for Debian [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/). Other images might be available [here](https://soft.lafibre.info/).

If you install an older Debian version, you can then point your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ <version> main non-free contrib
```

That will let you `apt-get` additional software that was available at the time.

These steps might get you close enough to the software and tools you used at the time, as an alternative to trying to match the tutorial to the tools now available.